# What does "could be taken to stand for" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This is the history of the word "item" taken from the American Heritage Dictionary.

"The word item seems to us to be very much a noun, whether it refers to an article in a collection or a bit of information. But it began its life in English (first recorded before 1398) as an adverb meaning "moreover, also, in addition." Item was typically used in front of each object listed in an inventory, as we might put also. This use in English simply reflects a meaning of the word in Latin. However, it is easy to see how item **could be taken to stand for** the thing that it preceded, and so we get, for example, the sense "an article included in an enumeration." The first such usages are found in the 1500s, while the sense "a bit of information" is not found until the 1800s.""

**"take for"**

a. to assume to be: I took it for a fact.(Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

**"stand for"**

a. to represent; symbolize: P.S. stands for “postscript.”(Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

It sounds to me like a combination of these two definitions but what gives me reservations is that "for" appears in both of them, and I've never heard of a rule which states that two phrasal verbs cancel each other words out.

Comment: _Taken to_ = understood to. _Stand for_ = represent.

Comment: It's completely irrelevant that preposition ***for*** happens to occur in the "usage example" of the first definition you've cited. That definition already includes ***to assume to be*** as equivalent to ***to take for***, and the cited usage could just as well have been *I took it **to be** a fact.*

Answer (score 0):

*"could be taken to stand for"*

In that context, "Stand for", means "stand in for", or "stand in place of".

"[x] could be taken for [y]", means that the taker forms the idea that [x] was, in fact, [y]. Presumably 'take' is used because the taker 'takes away' (from the particular situation) the idea that x is y.